# Cannot calculate tripcost, complains about NoneType instead

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def hotelcost(nights):
    cost = 140
    return nights * cost

def planeridecost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

def rentalcarcost(days):
    cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        cost - 50
    elif days >= 3:
        cost - 20
    else:
        return cost
def tripcost(city,days,spendingmoney):
    return planeridecost(city) + hotelcost(days) + rentalcarcost(days) + spendingmoney
    print tripcost
    return tripcost

tripcost("Los Angeles",5,600)
```

I cannot solve this problem in Python. I have tried several other codes to do same operation but I can't execute:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 28, in <module>:
  File "python", line 25, in tripcost:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: No. Firstly, don't shout; secondly, you have to post the full traceback.

Comment: For the future please describe your problem more clearly. What isn't working? Are there any error messages? Are you getting a result you didn't expect?

Comment: where do you define the spendingmoney variable that you try to sum?

Comment: I did not define "spending money". I just followed the instructions. But I knew I had to define it. So, can I just put spendingmoney = 600?

Comment: Im still getting an error"Oops, try again. Oops! Did you accidentally delete the trip_cost function?"

Comment: @jester112358 `spendingmoney` is a parameter of the `tripcost` funcion.

Comment: @VijayBoopathy `trip_cost` or `tripcost`?

Comment: It's given as "trip_cost". But for convenience I've coded it as "tripcost"

Comment: @VijayBoopathy Well, pick one.

Answer (score 1):

Your `rentalcarcost()` function only returns the `cost` value in one of the branches:

```
def rentalcarcost(days):
    cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        cost - 50
    elif days >= 3:
        cost - 20
    else:
        return cost
```

So only if `days` is smaler than 3 will you return a cost. The other branches need to include `return` statements too, or you'll end up returning `None` instead:

```
def rentalcarcost(days):
    cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        return cost - 50
    elif days >= 3:
        return cost - 20
    else:
        return cost
```

Comment: Im still getting an error"Oops, try again. Oops! Did you accidentally delete the trip_cost function?"

Comment: @VijayBoopathy: perhaps you want to *print* the return value of the `trip_cost()` function call. With the change in my answer, the code at least doesn't fail and returns `1955`.

Comment: @VijayBoopathy: functions can return. Top-level code cannot.

Comment: @VijayBoopathy: you don't need to add in the functions I didn't correct. I gave you a corrected version of `rentalcarcost`; just use the rest of your code as written (although anything bast the `return` line in `tripcost()` is not going to be executed as the function exits when you use `return`).

Answer (score 0):

Rentalcarcost function returns None for cases where days>=7 and days>=3.Do it like below:

```
def rentalcarcost(days):
    cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        return (cost - 50)
    elif days >= 3:
        return (cost - 20)
    else:
        return cost
```

Your tripcost function has 2 returns and the second one is useless.